# Running Apache Tomcat 7 in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to run Apache Tomcat 7 on the Eclipse. But I am facing some problems. I configured the tomcat libraries. Then I also imported the war files in the existing workspace. Then I tried running the index jsp page. But I am getting error 
"Unable to load page". Cannot resolve proxy hostname. I am not sure why the tomcat is starting now.

Can someone tell me what is this error ?

Comment: Please provide your error here

Answer (score 0):

To run Tomcat, you need to either add a server using Eclipse's tomcat plugin or modify the run/debug configurations to point to your application's server.xml. 
The error you're getting suggests that tomcat is not running or that it's not configured properly.
What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am getting the following when I try to the tomcat server. I tried using jsp index file. 

Unable to load page

Problem occurred while loading the URL http://localhost:8081/HelloWorldExample/

Cannot resolve proxy hostname ()

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows then go to run type services.msc a window will open up from there stop the apache tomcat service and then try to run it from eclipse.

or just change the port numbers it might be used by some other application